# How to convert this string to some array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using one 3rd party plugin which uses stringify and gives me something like:

```
["ProjectB","ProjectA","Paris"]
```

It was an array but it used stringify and serialized into this format.How do I get back my array from this? Now I could very well use split and then remove 1st and last character from every string and get it but I don't want to do that manually. Is that any built in utility that can do that for me?

Comment: What you have shown is an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have like `var str = '["ProjectB","ProjectA","Paris"]';`

Try using,

```
var array = JSON.parse(str); //will return you an array
```

As @AlexMA pointed out: `JSON.parse` is not supported in old browsers so you are better off using jQuery version like below,

```
var array = $.parseJSON(str);
```

Comment: JSON.parse is not always supported in older browsers, so the jQuery method might be safer if you can use it.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON bottom of page

Comment: @AlexMA Well that was my intention when adding `var array = $.parseJSON(str);`.. but true.. I need to say it in my post.

Comment: @Vega I wasn't criticizing your post, just adding to it!

Comment: @AlexMA You commented out a good point and it is very valid.. I just wanted to give credit to who ever commented it that is why I added your name in the post. I might have not added that browser support if you have not pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
JSON.parse(your_arr_str);
```

or jquery

```
$.parseJSON(your_arr_str);
```